# connection timeout for NX Server anymore

Tags: nomachine-nx

Hi I managed successfully to connect to NX server on Ubuntu machine using NX Client from my windows machine (version) but suddenly, I have got timeout connection error with the following log info from windows no machine client

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 5284
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: 10.10.13.125 on port: 22
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
HELLO NXSERVER - Version 3.5.0-11 - LFE
NX> 105 Hello NXCLIENT - Version 3.5.0
NX> 134 Accepted protocol: 3.5.0
NX> 105 Set shell_mode: shell
NX> 105 Set auth_mode: password
NX> 105 Login 
NX> 101 User: wshowair
NX> 102 Password: ***
NX> 103 Welcome to: enb-test user: wshowair
NX> 105 Listsession --user="wshowair" --status="suspended\054running" --geometry="1366x768x32+render" --type="unix-gnome" 
NX> 127 Available sessions: 

Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name
------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------

NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: wshowair
NX> 105 Start session with: --link="adsl" --backingstore="1" --encryption="1" --cache="16M" --images="64M" --shmem="1" --shpix="1" --strict="0" --composite="1" --media="NX> 280 Exiting on signal: 15
```

Meanwhile I have got the following log message on Ubuntu I have got the following output from /var/log/messages:

```
wshowair@enb-test:~$ tail -n30 /var/log/messages
Jan 15 11:05:51 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11475]: Session '3CFE5967E8DC57A0EA75FE19ACC9ACE6' started by user 'wshowair'. 'NXShell::handler_session_start'
Jan 15 11:05:51 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11620]: Using port '1001' on node 'enb-test' for session 'unix-gnome'. Logger::log nxnode 6243
Jan 15 11:05:51 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11620]: Using host from available host list: '10.10.13.125'. Logger::log nxnode 6244
Jan 15 11:06:49 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11475]: Received 'PIPE' signal: this signal is ignored by NX Server 'main::Static'
Jan 15 11:06:49 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11475]: Cannot read from stdin: NX client disconnected before the 'bye' message: exiting cleanly 'NXShell::handleExitRequests'
Jan 15 11:06:49 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11475]: User 'wshowair' from '192.168.101.225' logged out. 'NXLogin::reset'
Jan 15 11:06:49 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11475]: Received 'PIPE' signal: this signal is ignored by NX Server 'main::Static'
Jan 15 11:06:51 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11620]: ERROR: run command: process: 11644 finished with: 1 Logger::log nxnode 3907
Jan 15 11:06:51 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11653]: ERROR: Error when monitoring session: Unexpected termination of nxagent 'NXSessionMonitor::__setSessionStatus'
Jan 15 11:06:52 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11653]: Directory '/home/wshowair/.nx/C-enb-test-1001-3CFE5967E8DC57A0EA75FE19ACC9ACE6' renamed into '/home/wshowair/.nx/F-C-enb-test-1001-3CFE5967E8DC57A0EA75FE19ACC9ACE6' for further investigation Logger::log nxnode 6432
Jan 15 11:06:53 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[11620]: Session 'unix-gnome' on port '1001' failed. Logger::log nxnode 6513
Jan 15 11:06:59 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11646]: ERROR: NXNodeExec: Cannot kill nxssh process: No such process 'NXNodeExec::exec'
Jan 15 11:06:59 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[11646]: User 'wshowair' from '192.168.101.225' logged out. 'NXLogin::reset'
Jan 15 11:31:00 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: User 'wshowair' logged in from '192.168.101.225'. 'NXLogin::set'
Jan 15 11:31:01 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Selected node host:localhost with port:22 'main::selectNode'
Jan 15 11:31:01 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Current selected node: localhost is in status: running  'main::selectNode'
Jan 15 11:31:01 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Selected session type: unix-gnome allowed in the profile of user: wshowair 'NXShell::Static'
Jan 15 11:31:03 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Session 'D038E20195545ACA3EBB4F14FDF14371' started by user 'wshowair'. 'NXShell::handler_session_start'
Jan 15 11:31:04 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12415]: Using port '1002' on node 'enb-test' for session 'unix-gnome'. Logger::log nxnode 6243
Jan 15 11:31:04 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12415]: Using host from available host list: '10.10.13.125'. Logger::log nxnode 6244
Jan 15 11:32:02 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Received 'PIPE' signal: this signal is ignored by NX Server 'main::Static'
Jan 15 11:32:02 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Cannot read from stdin: NX client disconnected before the 'bye' message: exiting cleanly 'NXShell::handleExitRequests'
Jan 15 11:32:02 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: User 'wshowair' from '192.168.101.225' logged out. 'NXLogin::reset'
Jan 15 11:32:02 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12270]: Received 'PIPE' signal: this signal is ignored by NX Server 'main::Static'
Jan 15 11:32:03 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12415]: ERROR: run command: process: 12439 finished with: 1 Logger::log nxnode 3907
Jan 15 11:32:04 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12448]: ERROR: Error when monitoring session: Unexpected termination of nxagent 'NXSessionMonitor::__setSessionStatus'
Jan 15 11:32:04 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12448]: Directory '/home/wshowair/.nx/C-enb-test-1002-D038E20195545ACA3EBB4F14FDF14371' renamed into '/home/wshowair/.nx/F-C-enb-test-1002-D038E20195545ACA3EBB4F14FDF14371' for further investigation Logger::log nxnode 6432
Jan 15 11:32:05 enb-test NXNODE-3.5.0-9[12415]: Session 'unix-gnome' on port '1002' failed. Logger::log nxnode 6513
Jan 15 11:32:11 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12441]: ERROR: NXNodeExec: Cannot kill nxssh process: No such process 'NXNodeExec::exec'
Jan 15 11:32:11 enb-test NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[12441]: User 'wshowair' from '192.168.101.225' logged out. 'NXLogin::reset'
```

I have tried to re-install nxserver & nxnode on server Ubuntu machine and nomachine windows client but still having the same connection timeout error, any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of failure can be caused by several types of issues that may be hard to diagnose.  Often NX server has been working fine, but some software-update or configuration change on the server creates a configuration that is incompatible with NX.

For the symptoms you are seeing above, the first check is to see whether your remote Xsession is setup to run `xscreensaver`.  Shell-in to the server and run `killall xscreensaver` and try and connect with NX again.  If this works, reconfigure your Xsession, disabling the screen saver function.

Other things you can try:

- Delete your `${HOME}/.nx` directory, which contains cached session information
- Create a new user and try connecting as that user.  If this works, it confirms that you have some local Xsession settings that NX is unable to tolerate.  You could try and work these out, or if you want to take drastic measures, you could backup your home directory and create a new one, which will remove all your `.*` settings files and should restore a working NX.

Answer (score 0):

You must verify if the user you are trying to start with in NX is added in nxserver

nxserver --adduser user

If it is not added in the nxserver, it will not start the session.

regards